# SubscriptionLost when trying to subscribe to real time events with BLPData.jl

Tags: julia, bloomberg, blpapi

Using Julia 1.8.3, and following the example from the [BLPData website](https://felipenoris.github.io/BLPData.jl/v0.3/#Subscription-1), I get the following:

```
julia> using BLPData

julia> session = BLPData.Session()
Session services available: Set(["//blp/refdata", "//blp/mktdata"])

julia> topic = "//blp/mktdata/ticker/TYH3 Comdty?fields=BID,ASK"
"//blp/mktdata/ticker/TYH3 Comdty?fields=BID,ASK"

julia> subscription_list = BLPData.subscribe(session,topic)
Subscription List Topics

24NOV2022_10:04:58.609 52528:5992 WARN blpapi_subscriptionmanager.cpp:7338 blpapi.session.subscriptionmanager.{1} SubscriptionLost for unknown data set with stream id 1 { ConnectionContext=[0/1] }

    1 => BLPData.SubscriptionTopic(CorrelationId(5), "//blp/mktdata/ticker/TYH3 Comdty?fields=BID,ASK")

julia>
```

My `topic` is not exactly the same as the one used on the [BLPData website](https://felipenoris.github.io/BLPData.jl/v0.3/#Subscription-1) but both return the same message.

Does anyone have experience running this?

Comment: Additional note: I successfully ran a similar code in Python as I was trying to rule out a potential issue with Bloomberg.